# Arduino's analogWrite() - does it work the same way for NPN and PNP transistors?

Tags: arduino, transistors, pwm, esp8266

If I'd like to control the NPN transistor with PWM, I'd just have connected the transistor to the output of the Arduino (or actually, ESP8266) and set `analogWrite()`.

But what if I want to control the PNP and NPN transistor? Can I control PNP transistor using the same function? Will connected LEDs by these transistors be illuminating in the same way with the same configuration of `analogWrite()`?

Comment: You can drive PNP and NPN transistors with PWM, the problem is that PNP are more suitable as a high side switch, which can get tricky for a beginner if your supply is higher than your GPIO voltage (as in, you're probably going to need an NPN part anyway). So unless the device you are controlling has particular needs you'll be better off with NPN as a low side switch.

Comment: Also, PWM frequency may be important as switching the diffusion capacitance of BJTs can be an issue when using base drive (as opposed to emitter drive, for example.)

Comment: The thing is, that I need to use GPIO2 and GPIO15 of my ESP8266 because of lack of available GPIOs. GPIO2 is connected through pull-up resistor to VCC so I can use it only with PNP transistor because I can't switch GPIO2 to output. While GPIO15 is connected to GND through pull-down resistor so I can use it only with NPN transistor because I can't switch GPIO15 to input. And here comes the question: If I use NPN and PNP transistors and use `analogWrite()` for controlling these transistors which controls LEDs, will they be illuminating the same?

Comment: @Defozo -- This is going to sound harsh, and I'm sorry for it, but: I think you fundamentally misunderstand how pull-up/down affect GPIOs. Having it being pulled whatever way does not force you to use a particular type of transistor. Also, what does switching a GPIO to input has to do with driving a transistor?

Comment: Oops, I thought that I need my pin to be configured as input in order to drive a transistor... but nevermind... Now I know that I just simply needs my pin configured as output and LOW for PNP transistor to turn on my LED and HIGH for NPN transistor to turn on my LED, right?

Comment: So if I have pull-up resistor connected to GPIO2, the state of the pin as from 'transistor's point of view' is HIGH and if I make GPIO2 HIGH in my program it won't change anything because it would be still HIGH but if I change GPIO2 to LOW, it should be LOW from the 'transistor's point of view'?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't force me to use a particular type of transistor. My LEDs would just be turned on during startup because I can control my GPIOs about 200 ms after powering up.

Comment: I think the pull up/downs are in the range of 10~15k in the ESP/node clones. For 3.3V, that means that pulling a signal that is pulled-up will require your device to sink 0.33mA, which is well into the realm of feasibility. So think of it this way: when your device has booted and you put its output in low impedance mode, you can easily overpower the pull up/downs, so it doesn't matter for them which way they're pulled to.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I can overpower them. But if I choose wrong tranistor (eg. NPN for pin which is pulled-up), then the transistor will be satured during startup, so my LED will shine. However, if I choose correct transistor (eg. PNP for pin which is pulled-up), then the transistor won't be satured during startup, so my LED won't shine in that time. So, if I don't want my LEDs to shine during startup, then, in a way, I'm forced to use a particular type of transistor, right?